# Citrix receiver error 1000119

Tags: citrix

I am trying to run Citrix receiver on the Xenial version of Ubuntu, but I am getting this error below

> ERROR:
>
> Cannot connect to "0.0.0.2 - Remote Desktop Connection"
>
> Unknown error 1000119. Verify your connection settings and try again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 93):

Remove `cacerts` and link to `/etc/ssl/certs` by the following commands

```
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/
sudo rm -rf cacerts
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts
```

Source: [comment by bdetweiler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901448/citrix-receiver-error-1000119/1018091#comment1651505_921338) which helped me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: you need to `sudo` before rm and ln but yes perfect

Comment: This helped me, for the first time ever, get Citrix Receiver working in a Linux distribution! Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the above solution. But still the same error. Can somebody pls help

Comment: Just added sudo as commented, worked for me too!

Comment: Suggest `sudo mv cacerts cacerts.OLD` rather than just a straight up purge.

Comment: @CoreyS. The folder can safely be deleted. First, the Citrix client is not a valuable piece of software (you don't break your system), and second, the certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` are more comprehensive (you don't lose anything). See [Citrix receiver 13.10 on Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064452/citrix-receiver-13-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-1/1069929#1069929) for background reading.

Comment: That worked !!! Thanks alot. it saves my day!!!

Comment: This solved my issue.  Thanks @validom!

Comment: This also solves another issue that appears before you can even login: 

"An SSL connection to the server couldn't be established because the server's certificate was not trusted." Thank you!

Comment: This wone worked for me too.. :)

Answer (score 5):

I got it. Linking the system's certificates to the ICA's also works:

`sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts`

with ignoring the warnings regarding duplicates.

Comment: It's worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the equivalent problem. The best solution I was able to find at the moment in Xenial was to downgrade to the [13.2 x64 version of Citrix Receiver](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-receiver-for-linux/receiver-for-linux-13-2.html) and be sure to follow the [standard procedures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) with respect to linking certificates, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by getting the root cert. 
In my case it was Verisign, so I downloaded the root 10 cert from https://www.symantec.com/theme/roots

Get root 10. It'll be a file called `verisign-universal-root-certification-authority-en.pem`
sudo copy it into `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts`

It worked straight after.

Comment: This worked for me: `cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/;
rm -rf cacerts;
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts;`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to put in

```
8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4
```

as DNS in the network manager

Comment: Upvoting as this error message was a DNS issue for me too (the certificates above didn't solve it).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by use the following Steps

```
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
wget https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt

curl https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/GetAttachment/969/821026 > comodorsacertificationauthority.crt
exit
```

I get solution from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062679/cannot-connect-to-0-0-0-2-published-app-name-in-citrix-receiver-ica-client

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to permanently solve the issue with the solutions here. I found a suggestion [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/citrix-receiver-18-10-0_64-on-slackware-14-2_64-cannot-connect-to-0-0-0-2-no-such-file-or-directory-4175642666/) which solved my problem.

- Install [Chrome Citrix Workspace plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/citrix-workspace/haiffjcadagjlijoggckpgfnoeiflnem?hl=en)

If you don't know the URL the app asks you for; it is the URL of your organisation's "Citrix storefront" (where you download your .ica files)